# Service fabric failing with Service Status: fabric:/testsfApplication/tessf is not ready, no container is running

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have a Asp.net Core stateless Service fabric application which was working fine locally but suddenly started giving the above errors on build and deploy. I reset docker locally and also service fabric but it still fails with the same error. I tried to then create a test application which is just an Asp.net core web api with a values controller and converted it into a service fabric application. It also fails with the same error.
I checked my event log and can see this error message from docker
Handler for POST /containers/create returned error: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\5rn5xyjl.zea\NanoUtilities:c:\remote_debugger_utilites:ro': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist.

Not sure what is going wrong. Any pointer please ?

Comment: I have exacly the same problem. Did you update to VS 15.7.2 or the latest SF build??

Comment: I updated VS to 15.7.3 and the latest SF build and it magically works. Worried though since I am not sure what was wrong and what fixed it.